# initialize 1000 map elements

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

Just as we can initialize vectors as:

```
  vector<int> var1(2000,1);
```

Is it possible to initialize map;

```
  map<int, int>var2;
```

for 2000 variables...the reason why I want to initialize are two:

1. In case I access an element in future e.g. map[100]..I want that map[100]=0
2. The second reason is that I am using a minimum priority queue which for comparison uses the second value of map i.e. the value stored in map[0]...map[100].
3. I don't want to use vectors as my indices are really skewed and this leads to a lot of wasted space...i.e. my indices are map[0], map[30], map[56],map[100],map[120],map[190], etc.

Is there some way by which I can initialize the map for say 1000 variables...I am also open to using any other data structure.

Also the conventional way of initializing map i.e.

```
  map<int, int> m = map_list_of (1,2) (3,4) (5,6) (7,8);
```

The above way does not work in my case...is there some other way out.PLEASE HELP

EDIT: I can not use for loop as:

This way the key remains fixed which I don't want since the distribution of my keys is skewed. In essence applying for loop in this way is the same as that of vector and this I don't want

Comment: `std::map<>` does not allow multiple values with the same key, so how could this be possible in the first place? Do you really want `std::multimap<>`? "*In case I access an element in future e.g. map[100]..I want that map[100]=0*" This is already how it would work if the key weren't present in the `map<>`...

Comment: Can't you use a for loop? What keys/values would those 1000 values involve if you used some kind of magic constructor that does the same as the vector's?

Comment: @ildjarn Actually mapping is not a problem..i want to map one value to one key...the problem is I want to initialize these single key elements.

Comment: Then your corollary to `std::vector<>` is flawed, because you're inserting 2000 of the same value, not unique values.

Comment: No... the collary is right..just that i want to access elements in unique key way like std::vector<> a; a[2] is the same as map1[2].

Comment: No, the corollary isn't right -- `vector<int> var1(2000,1);` creates a vector with 2000 identical values; you can't have identical keys in a map.

Comment: right but now if I access the elements say var1[300] then its value is 1 which is exactly what I want

Comment: Which is _exactly the same_ with a default-constructed `std::map<int, int>`. See [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at).

Comment: The problem with the default constructor is it gives me a 0 as default whereas I want a one by default

Comment: If you really wanted it like that, you could always wrap it in a struct that initializes it to 1, and has an implicit `operator int()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a surrogate instead of an `int` in your map, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct surrogate_int {
    int val;
    surrogate_int() : val(1) {}
    surrogate_int& operator=(const int v) { val=v; }
    operator const int() { return val; }
};

int main() {
map<int,surrogate_int> m;
    m[5] = 5;
    m[7] = 7;
    m[9] = 9;
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) {
        cout << i << ":" << m[i] << endl;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: No...I am looking for '1' rather than 0

Comment: @JannatArora Take a look at the update. It is not pretty, but it does the job.

Comment: +1, this works, but IMHO @JannatArora you're better off rethinking whatever it is you're doing than taking this approach. If `1` can hold some kind of special meaning for you, I fail to see why `0` cannot be made to have that meaning instead

Answer (score 0):

You can do the old fashied way of using loops:

```
map<int, int> var2;
for (int = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
  var2[i] = 0;
}
```

On the other hand usign the subscript notation (`var2[x]`) will add the value with its default value (0 for `int`) if the key does not exist in the map yet.

Comment: But _why_? `std::map<int,int>::operator[]` will already insert a value of `0` for you when you index a key that isn't present.

Comment: @ildjarn I think that should be an answer.

Comment: @Attila This way the key remains fixed between 0 to 1000 which I don't want since the distribution of my keys is skewed. In essence applying for loop in this way is the same as that of vector and this I don't want

Comment: @JannatArora - if you can map the numbers 0-999 to the keys you _do_ want, you can still do the `for` loop, but apply the mapping when you are indexing the map.  You _will_ have to have some algorithm that provides that mapping for you, otherwise you would not be able to do it in an initializer either (uless you were planning to hand-list all the 1000 values -- in which case you should read the values form a config file instead of storing them in the source, I think)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to define your own data type that has an embedded priority (defaulting to 0, presumably), and define a comparator that uses that priority to order objects of your type.  Something like

```
class MyType {
  int val;
  int priority;
  MyType(int val, int priority = 0): val(val), priority(priority) {}
  bool operator<(MyType const& other) { return priority < other.priority; }
}
```

Then you can just make a priority queue of that type, avoiding using a map at all.

Answer (score 0):

boost::assign:

///from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html

```
#include <boost/assign/list_inserter.hpp> // for 'insert()'
#include <boost/assert.hpp> 
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::assign; // bring 'insert()' into scope

{
    map<string,int> months;  
    insert( months )
        ( "january",   31 )( "february", 28 )
        ( "march",     31 )( "april",    30 )
        ( "may",       31 )( "june",     30 )
        ( "july",      31 )( "august",   31 )
        ( "september", 30 )( "october",  31 )
        ( "november",  30 )( "december", 31 );
    BOOST_ASSERT( months.size() == 12 );
    BOOST_ASSERT( months["january"] == 31 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You don't need to do anything at all. When you use `operator[]` to access a key that was not previously inserted, a new value is created, initialized to 0 and a reference returned. There is no need to initialize at all.</strike>

Also nNote, that when you insert elements into the map, the key is fixed, so if you decide to insert 100 elements, the keys will be fixed, which will make initialization useless in most use cases.

I would avoid the complexity of initializing the map, and rather have a helper function that replaces `operator[]` as:

```
int &getValue( std::map<int,int>& m, int key ) {
    return *m.insert( std::make_pair(key,1) ).first;
}
```

There is no need to preallocate the nodes. The trick is that `insert` is equivalent to a lookup if the value already exists in the map, but will add the element if it was not present. Attempting an insert of a `pair<int,int>(key,1)` will insert `1` into the container if it did not exist before, but will leave the value untouched if it was already there. Because `insert` returns an iterator, we can use that to obtain a reference into the stored value.

The use would be *just* as simple as access through `operator[]`:

```
int x = getValue( mymap, 31 ); // 1 if 31 was not present in the map, else
                               // the value stored there.
getValue(mymap,31) = 5;        // Ugly, I know... but still simpler than providing
                               // an extra type, and preinitializing the container
```

Comment: He wants the value returned to be a 1, not 0, when a key that wasn't previously inserted is accessed.

Comment: @Prætorian: *In case I access an element in future e.g. map[100]..I want that map[100]=0* That sounds like he wants `0`... am I missing something?

Comment: You're right, he does say that in the question. But if you dig through the comments below it he claims he actually needs a 1.